# I did "git init" but getting error "does not appear to be a git repository"

Tags: git, ssh, atlassian-sourcetree

I want to create a git repository on an SSH server.

I’m on this path `/webseiten/staging`. I created a folder named `hellauf.git` there, and in this folder I used the command `git init --bare`. There are now the following folders and files:

[image: Git repository file layout]

Permissions are like the following:

```
-rw-r----- 1 u322494 nobody   66 Sep 15 14:46 config
-rw-r----- 1 u322494 nobody   73 Sep 15 14:46 description
-rw-r----- 1 u322494 nobody   23 Sep 15 14:46 HEAD
drwxr-x--- 2 u322494 nobody 4096 Sep 15 14:46 hooks
drwxr-x--- 2 u322494 nobody 4096 Sep 15 14:46 info
drwxr-x--- 4 u322494 nobody 4096 Sep 15 14:46 objects
drwxr-x--- 4 u322494 nobody 4096 Sep 15 14:46 refs
```

I now have a local repository and want to push my master to this remote on the SSH server.

I’m using SourceTree, and there I filled out the URL/Path with:

```
sshadminaccount@url:/webseiten/staging/hellauf.git
```

But when I try to push, I get the following error message:

```
git -c diff.mnemonicPrefix=false -c core.quotepath=false -c credential.helper=sourcetree push -v --tags staging refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master 
Pushing to sshadminaccount@url:/webseiten/staging/hellauf.git

fatal: '/webseiten/staging/hellauf.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
Completed with errors, see above
```

What’s going wrong here?

Comment: So _do_ you have the correct access rights?  Can you, for instance, do a file listing of the remote `hellauf.git` directory?

Comment: Just to be clear, you did `mkdir hellauf.git` followed by `cd hellauf.git` and `git init --bare`? Because that's what you should have done but it's not clear from your description.

Comment: Typically, I would expect /webseiten/staging/hellauf.git` to be a bare repository, but you have created a non-bare repo there (so all the meta files are in /webseiten/staging/heallauf.git/.git`).

Comment: @trentcl Yes i did this.

Comment: I did a bare @WilliamPursell